# Запустить python скрипт из программы на C

Tags: python, python-3.x, c

Есть питон-скрипт, который надо запустить на из программы на С, при этом передав ему argv. Пытаюсь запускать так:execv(path, argv). Где path - путь до скрипта. Однако ничего не происходит, при запуске скрипта из консоли все проходит нормально. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: запустить python и его параметр путь до скрипта

Comment: Мне нужно запустить из программы на С

Comment: поясняю, в качестве path - python, аргумент - скрипт:  execv(path_to_python, path)

Comment: в c++ по крайней мере есть функция system() которая в терминал пишет то что ей пришло в параметры, если в с есть такая, то: system("python3 Script.py");

Comment: После `execv()` вызовите `perror()` и увидите сообщение об ошибке. Только учтите, после успешного `execv()` вашей программы больше не существует,  в том же процессе ее код заменится на код интерпретатора python, выполняющего скрипт. Возможно вместо `exec` вам надо вызывать `system()` (или `popen()`)

Comment: Или использовать Python/C API для запуска интерпретатора прямо в процессе сишноц программы.